# Oracle Apex add several links in tree leaves/nodes

Tags: tree, oracle-apex

I am trying to use the tree region in Oracle Apex. While it is straightforward to add a link on a leaf/node of the tree, what I would like to do is slightly different. I would like to add *several* links on each leaf/node (e.g. accessible through icons). Clicking on these icons would either take me to another page of the application or open a page via a modal page.

I have looking around, and it seems there is no way to do that without playing with some javascript code.

Anybody has been successful or tried something similar ?

Any pointer appreciated

Comment: I tried the jQuery solution pointed out in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46176845/adding-html-tag-into-the-title-of-the-tree-query-in-oracle-apex. I added in the TITLE column a set of links via '<a href="....">link</a>  and although it seems to modify the html as expected the link generated can be clicked but does not do any redirect: it is as if the click was 'captured' and the link never followed

Comment: I don't have an exact answer. The way I would normally tackle this requirement is to have a small region on the page showing details for the selected record; in the region, I'd put buttons to open other pages or modals for the selected record.